# Query to Change/Update existing integer value to character value in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting data as integer (0,1,2) from the database table using a stored procedure. Now I want to write some query/modify my query to convert this to characters (A,B,C) and show it.

Basically I want to do like this:

- When I will find 0 in the table(as a record value), I'll make it A
- When I will find 1 in the table(as a record value), I'll make it B
- When I will find 2 in the table(as a record value), I'll make it C

My ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/update-existing-rows-with-squence-number-char-or-any-unique-data

I'm trying like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
update tbl_Test set Col1 = 'A' 
alter table tbl_Test alter column Col1 varchar not null
where Col1 = '0'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

But, ended with following error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'.

I tried it in following way also;But, no success

```
select convert(varchar,Col1)as Col1 from tbl_Test --Here I'm converting
--alter column Col1 to varchar
update tbl_Test set Col1 = 'A' 

where Col1 like '0'
```

Showing me error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number is an ascii code, you can use the [CHAR() function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187323.aspx)

If you want to start at zero, just use CHAR, but add 65. [(See the ASCII table for additional character possibilities)](http://www.asciitable.com/)

**EDIT:**
For example, this will take a numeric value and display it as a capitalized letter:

```
select CHAR(Col1+65) as Col1 from tbl_Test
```

Comment: I have clearly explained my question.Could you please give more specific answer?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main problems - you are trying to store a char in an int field. You need to either store the ASCII value of the character (add 65) in that field or create another table of type char (or varchar/nvarchar) and store it there.